# How to identify if Facebook user has Profile Photo or Not using Graph api?

Tags: android, android-fragments, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented Facebook GraphAPi for User Registration in my App.
I am getting all the Required Data Name, email, but unable to get to know that if a user has a profile picture set or not.
I looked for this answer, but unsuccessful. Unable to find the if it has facebook profile picture or not.

Comment: +1 for the funny question. Can you please post more details? How do you connect to the facebook from Android, for example. Ask a specific question regarding the code

Comment: Use a profile tracker and when you get the callback when the user logs in you can get the current profile and call getProfilePictureUri() on it.

Comment: @VeselinTodorov I am getting profile Picture URL. But if I set the Profile Pic from Facebook, I still get a Profile Pic Url of No image in my app. My question is that can I check If user has a Profile Pic or not in Facebook?

Comment: @VeselinTodorov How could I recognize a no image url from a Normal Profile Pic url of Facebook?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture - you need to add parameter `redirect=false` to get a data structure that will contain the image URL plus a property `is_silhouette` that holds `true` for users that do not have a profile picture set, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parameter `redirect=false` to get a data structure that will contain the image URL plus a property `is_silhouette`, that holds `true` for users that do not have a profile picture set, and `false` otherwise.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture